# How to make the facebook comments on my website and on page's wall post binded?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

everybody.

I am developing the facebook tab application. The functionality is pretty simple and is close to the blog.

1. Page Admin writes articles in the app, and the link to each article is posted on the page's wall via Graph API.
2. The wall post from step 1 contains a link to the application tab of the page with post_id passed via app_data parameter.
3. The article itself contains the facebook like and comments plugins on it. To attach this plugins I use the url of the external website on which pages are prepared for Facebook scraping (Open Graph tags and stuff).

And finally the question!

Is it possible to somehow manage the situation whenever user posts the comment inside an application tab, his comment automatically appears near the wall post performed in step 1?

I really hope that the question is clear. Any help, please?

Comment: How you posted on page's wall

Comment: I was using facebook-php-sdk. The info about the procedure was found here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Comment: I am using the same procedure.but the link is posted under the label "Recent Posts by Others on aBC".But I want to post it on Page wall.Have you used page access_token for posting

Comment: Yes, I was using page access token with publish_stream and manage_pages permissions requested before.

Comment: Thank you. Page acces_token worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish comments to a Post via the Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments

You will need to ensure that you have:

- Requested `publish_stream` permission from the user
- Indicate to the user very clearly that you are going to publish a comment when they do this (to do otherwise would not only break Platform Policy, but would be a crappy experience for users)
- Subscribe to the Javascript `comment.create` event which is fired when someone posts a comment in a comments plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be an appropriate solution